# Why Characters.Count Property fails When the Cell Value is Numeric?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying the code:

```
n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Characters.Count 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") _ 
 .Characters(n, 1).Font.Superscript = True
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.superscript

I have noticed that it fails with numeric value in `A1`.
Thus, after some research, I have found that it works with strings and fails if we write completely numeric value in A1:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As Variant
    Range("A1") = "2"
    a = Array(Range("A1").Characters)
    Debug.Print a(0).Count

End Sub
```

Obviously there is an error because of the *Unable to get the Count property of the Characters class*, as displayed in the local window:

[image]

---

Of course, if there is a value in A1, which cannot be parsed to numeric, then everthing is ok:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As Variant
    Range("A1") = "a34"
    a = Array(Range("A1").Characters)
    Debug.Print a(0).Count

End Sub
```

Produces this:

[image]

**The question:** Is there some documentation about this which explains the reason for this errors, or this is a hidden "feature", or some kind of internal Excel optimization, parsing numeric values to numbers? Or the Remark in the documentation that Characters is not a collection means exactly this?

- [Range.Characters Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters)

Comment: I suspect you'd see the same thing with any data type that can be formatted.

Comment: Characters.Count is a function that is datatype specific.  While numbers look like text, they really aren't until you cast them as such.  What you're asking for would be similar to a function that asked for "'Bob' + 1", since 'Bob' is text, you can't add to it.

Comment: @FrankBall - I see. Indeed, if I add `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"` on the error case it works quite well. However, I was hoping to see some kind of documentation, but probably this is a too general case... I guess.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary

Comment: @FrankBall - well this is documentation for the data types? I hoped for documentation, saying that `Characters.Count` property throws an error when we pass numeric value and runs ok when it is String. Somehow could not find anything here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters.count

Comment: This is the MS documentation on the function:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters.count and this is the documentation for the Characters object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters.  This is most likely the best that you'll find.

Comment: @FrankBall - thanks for the links and the efforts, but somehow they are not very explicit on the type value (like not at all).

Comment: Late reply, maybe helpful :-; The first paragraph in the help docu states: *"'   Returns a Characters object that represents a range of characters ►within the object ►text◄.
'   You can use the Characters object to format characters ►within a text string◄."* So implicitly you are always referring to the `Range` object allowing text content only (c.f. also Syntax definition).

Answer (score 0):

Your first example causes [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) to return true, and so it is treated as a number and not as text, which the Characters property requires.

```
Cells(1, 1) = "123.4"
Debug.Print IsNumeric(Cells(1, 1)) ' returns true

Cells(1, 1) = "123a"
Debug.Print IsNumeric(Cells(1, 1)) ' returns false
```